# How to format the integer value with leading zeros in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want format integer value by adding leading zeros and display it as string. For example, I have `3` and I want to display it as `003`. I want to do it in matlab.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `sprintf()`:

```
aa = sprintf('%03d', 3); % aa will be 003
```

Note that `aa` here is a `string`. Check out its [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Note that you can also use [string formatting](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html) in [`num2str`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) command as well:

```
num2str( 3, '%03d' );
```