# Variable number of left zeros in Matlab string

Tags: matlab, zero-pad

I want to do exactly what is on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092079/how-to-format-the-integer-value-with-leading-zeros-in-matlab), but instead of having to give a fixed number of left-side zeros, to be able to give the fixed number of digits that the number has to have in total.

For example, if I have the number `32`, and have a length of `4`, the result should be:

```
0032
```

But if on contrary I have the number `122`, then only one `0` should be padded:

```
0122
```

any ideas on how to achieve this on Matlab efficiently? `sprintf`?

Comment: I don't get the difference to the other question. It's exactly the same. I think you misunderstood what the answer in the other question is actually doing, but it does what you want.

Comment: @thewaywewalk sorry for my clumsiness

Comment: don't worry, that's what the duplicate function is for :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [string formatting](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html) in `num2str` as well as in `sprintf`:

```
num2str( 122, '%04d' );
```

or

```
sprintf( '%04d', 32 );
```

Answer (score 4):

This will left pad up to 4 0s

```
sprintf('%04d', some_value);
```

Comment: faster gun ;) kudos.

Comment: It was close I was just getting rid of my answer and upping yours. But you deleted yours quicker...:)